# How to fit the size of outermost html elements to the innermost element?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on building an email signature/contact form with images that will link to the respective information, like email, phone number, etc.

After each

element, there is some extra space at the bottom, which I do not want. This extra space is present in both the

and  tags of the nest, but not the  tags (these wrap appropriately). I'm not entirely sure what is causing this.

Relevant code:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="signature">
    <div class="content">
        <p class="name"><a href="#"><img src="/img.png"></a></p>
        <p class="address"><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir/..." target="_blank">
        <img src="/img2">
        </a></p>
        <p class="phone"><a href="tel:+5551234567"></a><a href="tel:+5551234567"><img src="/img3.png"></a></p>
        <p class="website"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img4.png"></a></p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.content {display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; padding:25px; border-left:1px solid #f26822;}
.content p {margin:0; font-family:Bliss2 Light; color:#81807f; font-size:16px;}
.content p a {color:#81807f; text-decoration:none;}
.content p a img {display:inline-block;} 
.content p.name a {font-family:Bliss2 Medium; color:#f26822; font-size:24px; text-transform:uppercase;}
.content p.title {font-family:Bliss2 Medium; color:#818181; font-size:22px; margin-bottom:15px;}
```

Comment: Add a fiddle to be able to see clearly what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Add following codes to your a tags

```
.content p a{display:block; line-height:0}
```

This code will remove white space between images.